# PHP foreach adding random gaps/whitespace

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table, inline-styles

I have the following PHP. Here I am creating a table, looping through the keys and values of my incoming data, adding them to the rows. When receiving the mail, it is adding random gaps/whitespaces in the inline styles, for example:

see `bord er:4px solid #E4F5FD;`

```
<td valign="top" style="padding:5px;border-collapse:collapse;bord er:4px solid #E4F5FD;text-transform:capitalize;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;">
```

and

see `background:#FFF  FFF;`

```
padding:5px;border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #E4F5FD;text-transform:capitalize;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;background:#FFF  FFF;color:#888888;
```

I have no idea why it is doing this, has anyone encountered this problem before?

Please keep in mind I am learning PHP, so be kind.

```
$data_output .= '<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background:#E4F5FD;border:0;width:680px;">';

    foreach ($data_html as $key => $value) {

        $data_output .= '<tr>';
        $data_output .= '<td valign="top" style="padding:5px;border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #E4F5FD;text-transform:capitalize;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;"><b>'.str_replace('_',' ',$key).'</b></td>';

        $values = '';
        foreach($value as $v) {
          $values .= $v.'<br />';
        }

        $z = '';
        if($values == ''){
            $z = $value;
        } else {
            $z = $values;
        }

        $data_output .= '<td valign="top" style="padding:5px;border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #E4F5FD;text-transform:capitalize;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;background:#FFFFFF;color:#888888;">'.str_replace('_',' ',$z).'</td>';
        $data_output .= '</tr>';
    }

    $data_output .= '</table>';


$from = 'website@bla.clo.uk';
$to = $_POST['email'];
$cc = 'me@bla.co.uk';
$subject = 'bla stuff';
$body = $data_output;

$headers = '';
$headers .= "From: $from\n";
$headers .= "Cc: $cc\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
$headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\n";
$headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo 'sent';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
    die();
}
```

Comment: How did you get that output with gaps? And is it working or not? (borders are applied or not, for instance)

Comment: i think the problem is not located inside that foreach... try to print out (echo) all the strings while you are generating the dataoutput, and compare with what is printed later.

Comment: i'd bet something else happens to $data_output after this piece of code.

Comment: The output is from Email Raw source.

Comment: I've added the last part of the PHP, $data_output just gets added to the body.

Comment: Sounds like you're sending this as mail. Are you sure you've set the mail headers for html rather than plain text? I'd wager the space is actually the MTA splitting on long strings.

Comment: Are those styles applied? If yes - than nothing to worry about. It is just some "feature" of you mail client. There is nothing in your code that can add random spaces

Comment: I just echo'ed the $data_output and you are right, the table code is fine. It's happening somewhere in the mail process. @FAngel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make sure that each line of content does not exceed 78 characters in length, nor that you exceed 998 continuous characters.

This was the issue, I added "\n" at the end of each row and cell to break the line content.

```
foreach ($data_html as $key => $value) {
        $data_output .=
        '<tr>'."\n".
        '<td style="border:4px solid #DADADA;background:#FFFFFF;text-transform:capitalize;">' . str_replace('_',' ',$key) . '</td>'."\n".
        '<td style="border:4px solid #DADADA;background:#FFFFFF;">' . $value . '</td>'."\n".
        '</tr>'."\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `$_data_output`.

Check with your settings in mail client you said you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with foreach loop but with tables. Sometimes (atleast in some browsers) the actual space between td's in html markup is rendered as it is into the webpage.

To avoid that, add `font-size:0` to your table class, then define fontsizes for your td class again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of email formatting - your issue is most likely the email client you are viewing the end result/email in - to test this out do a :

```
file_put_contents('test.htm',$data_output);
```

run this script and open the file and see if there are spaces in your styles in that outputted file (RAW output)

if so the script is the problem, if not your email client is formatting the email, as most email clients parse incoming emails, change styles and inline tags around, remove tags and all sorts of hideous things...

Do a gooogle search on - [this](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=emails%20get%20parsed%20on%20the%20client%20side&oq=emails%20get%20parsed%20on%20the%20client%20side&sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=email%20clients%20change/parse%20html%20source&oq=email%20clients%20change/parse%20html%20source&gs_l=serp.3...15277.17833.2.18028.13.12.1.0.0.7.460.3286.2-1j5j3.9.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.jjEWyKmYbGA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=bf5259a7412284cb&bpcl=38626820&biw=1517&bih=758), you will find related articles....